# Smart card select command returns 6A80 error, occasionally

Tags: c#, smartcard

I am writing a C# application which talks with EMV cards. The application is being written using the CardWerk Smartcard API [[http://www.smartcard-api.com/index.shtml]](http://www.smartcard-api.com/index.shtml%5d)

The app gives a select master card application command to the chip. The sequence is as follows :

1. Send the Select command to the card
2. If the response code is 61XX, then give a "GET RESPONSE" command with XX as expected length.
3. Read the data.

Most of the time, this works well. But occasionally, I get the the 6A80 error as the response to the "GET RESPONSE" command. What could the reason be?

Given below is the log of the error :

```
CMD 00A40400 (SELECT FILE) 07 A0000000041010 (' ......')
RSP 6139
CMD 00C00000 (GET RESPONSE) 39 
RSP 6A80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd ask CardWerk first. The status code is strange since it means "incorrect parameters in command data field", and I can't recognize one. If a trusted channel was established before, (this would at least justify existence of a command data field) this could mean, that the key used for secure messaging is wrong. Another explanation might be, that another process or thread also tries to operate on the card and spoils your result (a cyclic check for existence of a card could be such a process).

If you don't depend on information from the SELECT response, you could also try to reduce the effect, by setting P2 to 0C to suppress the response (if supported by your card), but this is more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @guidot . 

> Another explanation might be, that another process or thread also
> tries to operate on the card and spoils your result (a cyclic check 
> for existence of a card could be such a process).

this looks likely. Lemme look into it. 

> If you don't depend on information from the SELECT response

I dont actually use the select response. So, I'll try this too.

Thanks again.

Comment: On Windows you often don't have to look much further than the Certificate Proliferation Service (or whatever) in the service panel. Always disable that one when working with smart cards, it's amazing the amount of PCSC traffic that service manages to generate.